# CEF and the localized strings in *.pak files

Tags: c++, localization, chromium, chromium-embedded

I develop an application that uses the chromium embedded framework's control. I write in C++. I would like to use CEF mechanizm to localize an application if it exists. Can i embed the application's customized strings into CEF .pak files (en-US.pak and so on) so that i can retrieve these locolized strings in run-time? If so how can i embed them and how can i retrieve a given embedded string in my application code?

If .pak files is not a case then is there other ability to localize an application through CEF? Could you please share any idea?

Thanks